# adding two integers in method input by a user

Tags: java, methods

can anyone tell me why when i display the sum from my doSum method the two integers input by the user are not being added, it just displays the last integer being added. The point of the program is to use method overloading to get two integers input from the user, test to see if the input is an integer in getInt with without the low and high parameters then in getInt with high and low to test in the integers are between a certain range. then call the doSum to the summation method and display the integers input and the sum of them.

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in);
    String str; // to hold users input
    summation(key);
    // summation();

}

public static void summation (Scanner scan)
    {
    int low, high, sum; 
    low = getInt (scan, "enter and integer", 1, 100);         
    high =  getInt (scan, "enter and integer", 1, 100);
    sum = doSum(low,high); 
   // System.out.println("doSum " + [low,high] + "sum is " + sum );

     }

public static int getInt(Scanner scan, String prompt, int low, int high)
    {
     //call method getInt
    int integer = getInt (scan, "enter in integer"); 

    if (integer >=  low && integer <= high && high >= low)
        {
            System.out.println("input is in range");
        }
    else 
        {
        //if integer is not in range
        while (integer <= low || integer >= high || high<= low) 
        {
        System.out.println("error interger must be higher than or equal to low and lower than or equal to high, renter");
        integer = getInt (scan, "enter in integer");
        }
        }
        return integer;  
    }

public static int getInt(Scanner scan, String prompt)
    {

    String str; // to hold users input
    int integer = 0; 
    System.out.println (" Enter an integer ");
    hasInt(scan); 
    if (scan.hasNextInt())
    {
    str = scan.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("input is an integer"); 
    integer = Integer.parseInt(str); 

    }
    // if integer is not an integer, display error and repeat
    else 
    {
     while (!scan.hasNextInt())
    {
    System.out.println (" error, must be an integer, renter:  ");
    str = scan.nextLine();
    }
    }
    return integer; 
    }
public static int doSum (int start, int end)
{
    int sum = start++;
    start = start + 1;
    while (start <= end)
    {
    sum = start;
    start = start + 1; 
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum; 
}



public static boolean hasInt(Scanner scan)
    {
    return scan.hasNextInt(); 
    }
```

}

Comment: Why do you think your doSum method is correct? All you're doing is incrementing start until it equals end. Why can't you just do `start + end`

Comment: Thanks I did what you said and it worked, i didn't even understand what the while loop did the teacher gave it to us, using the same code any idea how i can make sure that the second integer from the user is equal to or higher than the first integer? I think its done somehow in the getInt method with the high and low

Answer (score 0):

Your `getInt()` method doesn't use your `hasInt()` method or the `prompt` parameter. Also, I suggest using a loop on the negation of the `hasInt()` test. I think you wanted something like

```
public static int getInt(Scanner scan, String prompt) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
    while (!hasInt(scan)) {
        System.out.println("Error, must be an integer, "
                + "please re-enter:  ");
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    return scan.nextInt();
}
```

Also, `doSum` should probably be something like

```
public static int doSum (int start, int end) {
    return start + end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing to the screen how you did like this:

```
System.out.println("doSum " + [low,high] + "sum is " + sum );
```

Try this:

```
System.out.println("doSum " + low + "," + high + "sum is " + sum );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your doSum method correctly. I think your not actually maintaining a running sum in the method, thus your always getting the last number because your assigning that last in your loop.

```
public static int doSum (int start, int end)
{
    int sum = start++;
    start = start + 1;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        sum += start;
        start = start + 1; 
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;
```

}